# Are site errors to be reported

Tags: discussion, support, error-message

This is the first site error I have seen, and I couldn't reproduce it.

Should we be reporting this type of error, or gathering data for submittal somewhere?

(fwiw: Win7/64,chrome 39.0.2171.99 m, and I clicked on "Looks OK")

[image: An error occurred when reviewing this item]

Comment: Note that these errors can be caused on your end as well (say your internet was down momentarily).

Comment: Besides the obvious two causes (SO code glitch, your connection going sour) there's another one that happens from time to time: the post you're reviewing has already been deleted. In this case, that's probably what happened.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, the question is still active

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it's better to report these if you can't readily blame another obvious cause. Whenever the system says you can't take an action that you're sure you should be able to take (especially with a rather non-descriptive message), then it's probably worth bringing up here.

Just make sure you include:

- What you were doing
- What you expected to happen
- Build and type of browser (note, 'beta' browsers are not officially supported)
- Any errors (also, check your console!)
- Anything else you find relevant

If you've been having issues with your connection all night and some CSS fails to load, then it's probably you.

The worst case is someone points you to a duplicate, or the cause turns out to be something difficult to diagnose on your side.

Comment: I think the latter is much, much worse than the former :)